# Return data after AFNetworking is done

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I got a async problem with my code. I got all of my webrequests in 1 class. One of my requests needs to return an NSMutableArray that another class needs to use. My webRequest code is here:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) getTournamentsInClub:(NSString *)clubGUID withDelegateViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSMutableArray *responseArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *URL = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"SomeURL=%@",clubGUID];
[manager POST:URL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    for (id obj in responseObject){
        //NSLog(@"obj: %@",[obj valueForKey:@"CustomerName"]);
        [responseArray addObject:obj];
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
return responseArray;
}
```

I call the method from a viewController like this:

[self handleClubTournaments:[[TournamentsWebService sharedToursWS] getTournamentsInClub:

```
//Show load screen. (hide in handler function)
GP_MobilAppDelegate *xdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[xdelegate showLoadingScreen:self.clubToursTableView andStatus:NSLocalizedString(@"loadTours", @"")];
```

And my handleClubTournaments function looks like this:

```
-(void) handleClubTournaments:(id)result {

GP_MobilAppDelegate *xdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if([result isKindOfClass: [NSError class]]) {
    // If an error has occurred, handle it
    [xdelegate hideLoadingScreen];
    [[TournamentsWebService sharedToursWS] showErrorMessageAccordingToFault:result];
    return;
}

if([result isKindOfClass: [SoapFault class]]) {
    [xdelegate hideLoadingScreen];
    // If a server error has occurred, handle it
    [[TournamentsWebService sharedToursWS] showErrorMessageAccordingToFault:result];
    return;
}

//Do something with result...

if ([result count] > 0) {

    NSLog(@"Antal klubturneringer: %d", [result count]);
    //Start by removing excisting tours
    [self.tournamentsSourceArray removeAllObjects];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray=[NSMutableArray array];

    for (GGTournamentData *t in result) { //cast object in result list and add them to array

        [tempArray addObject:t];

    }
    self.tournamentsSourceArray = [self sortByStringDate:tempArray]; //sort by date

    [tempArray release];

    NSLog(NSLocalizedString(@"tourLoadet", @""));
}

[self.clubToursTableView reloadData];
[xdelegate hideLoadingScreen];

//Scroll view
if (self.tournamentsSourceArray.count > 0) { //hvis det er turneringer..
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:[self findIndexOfMonthClosestToDate]];
    [self.clubToursTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
}
```

So my problem is that the NSMutableArray gets returned before my async task is done. I know a async task behaves like that, but how do i make sure that my handleClubTournaments function don't run before my webrequest(getTournamentsInClub) got some data for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you know how Asynchronous operations work. The `NSMutableArray` will never be set, because it is returned synchronously.
In your case, I suggest you to work with delegates.

```
- (void)getTournamentsInClub:(NSString *)clubGUID withDelegateViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController completionBlock:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *result))completionBlock {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSMutableArray *responseArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSString *URL = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"SomeURL=%@",clubGUID];
    [manager POST:URL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        for (id obj in responseObject) {
            [responseArray addObject:obj];
        }

        // Request finished. Call the block.
        completionBlock(responseArray);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

- (void)handleClubTournaments {
    GP_MobilAppDelegate *xdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[TournamentsWebService sharedToursWS] getTournamentsInClub:^(NSMutableArray *result) 
    {
         // Hide the Loading Indicator. Do something with the Result.
    }];

    // You can't access the result synchronously, therefore it's impossible to depend on it synchronously.
}
```

another way to return the data asynchronously would be blocks, similar to the `AFNetworking` solution.

You can read more about getting started with blocks [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) and how to use delegates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c).

Comment: I'm quite new to objective c programming does [self.delegate requestFinished:responseArray]; function like a return? just that it wont return before the task is done?

Comment: I've tried solving this by using blocks, but without success. Again I'm quite new so I'm not sure i did it the right way

Comment: No, not really. What you want is a blocking task, but this isn't how asynchronous works. The block, inside the `AFNetworking` statement, is called whenever the actual data has been downloaded. This is in the future, you can't know when. So your other program has to wait for it, you could show a `UILoadingIndicator` and dismiss it, when the delegate returns the data.

Comment: I got a loading indicator, take a look at my code (//Show load screen. (hide in handler function))

Comment: See my edit. You definitely have to read about asynchronous functions, as they're important and I don't think you understood them.

Comment: I understand how they work and the hole concept about multithreading, but i have no idea on how to handle them in objective c.

Comment: As said, with blocks (see my example above) or with delegates.

Comment: What's the completionBlock in your example?

Comment: It's a block, a method parameter I added to `getTournamentsInClub`.

Comment: Ok, i see you linked some stuff, ill read up on them, REALLY appreciate the help. Thanks Thanks Thanks:)

Comment: Hey just wanted to let you know that i got it working by the example you posted i just did a little correction in the caller so it patches the parameters i needed to pass: [[TournamentsWebService sharedToursWS] getTournamentsInClub:[self.club valueForKey:@"GUID"] completionBlock:^(NSMutableArray *result). So thx again ill mark it as the right answer.